# where can i find nifty 50 stocks list yearwise, from 5 years back

Tags: stock, stocktwits

I want to grab the list of nifty 50 stocks for say last 5 years , is there any website where i can easily find the list of stocks included and excluded in last 5 years , i just want the list of stocks .

Answer (score 0):

Check in the yahoo finance site and let me know If you find it helpful.

Comment: No, most of the websites have current list of nifty 50 , they didn't have it from 5 years back , btw thanks for your time .